# problem in sending and receiving data over mobile data hotspot

Tags: c++, networking, udp, wireshark, winsock

I have made a programming game which can be played online using C++, underlying protocol is UDP, the game was running smooth on my home wi-fi. When I am using my mobile hotspot, somehow the client and server cannot transmit packets. Server is hosted on VM on AWS.

I checked with wireshark, the client is sending the data and so is server. But they ain't receiving each other's packets. I have used VPN, and same result. Mobile hotspot is from my phone. What could be the reason?
PS: when I got two VM's one for client and one for server the game is running fine then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Firewall on your computer maybe?